# Update a WP database table from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-maps

I am using the WP Google Maps app. This allows map marker data to be entered on the back-end and displayed on maps on the front-end.

I am trying to adapt this so that an Author can create a post, and the data from the post populates the WP Google Maps table so that it appears on the map. In other words, enabling non-admin users to create map markers with additional fields.

The main information for WP Google Maps is stored in a table called wp_wpgmza. I have tried to write an SQL trigger that updates this table with data from wp_posts and wp_postmeta each time a new post is made but I can't crack it. Something about pulling from the two tables and the structure of wp_postmeta

Any suggestions on another way around this problem?

Thanks D

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress, hooks and filters are often used to accomplish most things like that.
You can easily use the following hooks that call your function before saving/inserting a post:

```
do_action('save_post', $post_ID, $post);
do_action('wp_insert_post', $post_ID, $post);
```

Here's a sample usage:

```
function my_function($post_ID, $post) {

}
add_action('save_post', 'my_function', 2);
```

Inside my_function you could use $wpdb->insert to enter the data to the table.

```
function my_function($post_ID, $post) {

    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'wpgmza';

    $data = array(
                'column1' => 'value1',
                'column2' => 'value2'
            );

    $wpdb->insert($table , $data);
}
add_action('save_post', 'my_function', 2);
```

Alternatively, you can use function_exists() and a function used by the plugin itself to insert to the map table.

```
function my_function($post_ID, $post) {

    if (function_exists('some_google_map_app_function')) {
        some_google_map_app_function();
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'my_function', 2);
```

**Note:** $post_ID, $post are parameters you can use to take a peak into the post data and/or pass along to that google maps function or insert to the table.

**Useful Resources:**

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Comment: Thans @Faisal Mudhir! This has moved me on greatly. One further issue. I can't get meta data with $map_address = get_post_meta ( $post_ID, 'address', true );  any thoughts?

Comment: @Douro It really depends whether the meta-data exists and whether you're passing the right stuff to target it. Make sure $post_ID is an int ID that represents the post that you're trying to target. Also make sure that 'address' is the meta _key_ of the meta-data -- double check in db: wp_postmeta (I think). I often debug similar situations using var_dump on different variables to check values and types. I'd use it on $map_address to see what am I getting.

Comment: Thanks @Faisal Mudhir.  I realise that I didn't mention that the post is being generated by a plugin and not WP back-end. So I am writing the function into the plugin and hopefully that works. Thanks again.